# Custom extension file not opening in iMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, imessage

In my app, I need to send some custom data files from one device to another, and I am trying to do this with Mail, iMessage/Message and Airdrop.

This works fine with Mail and Airdrop but with iMessage and it goes just fine, but on the receiving end, I am not able to open the files. It's just not allowing me to do anything with it.

Any ideas??

This is what my Document Type looks like:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>abc.png</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>ABC Custom Data type</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>Handler Rank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.company.abc.wd</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

This is how i am sending the data:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:currentDataSet forKey:@"actualData"];
NSData * meetingData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];

Meeting * dataItem = [[Meeting alloc]initWithData:meetingData
               type:@"com.abc.xyz.wd" subject:@"Meeting"
          previewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appIcon.png"]];

UIActivityViewController * activityController =
  [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[dataItem]
                                   applicationActivities:nil];

activityController.excludedActivityTypes =
       @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Not sure if you have to stick to the standard UTIs - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1 - Do you have code examples of what you are trying to do when attaching the file to the Message, are you using `addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:`?

Comment: Do you want to send only PNG files? if not you can use below code which sends/detects all kind of formats ```<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
   <array/>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>com.jungleDisk.file</string>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Owner</string>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.data</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>```

Comment: @Ashutosh, did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue and came across this thread.

Answer (score 9):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536866/2313512) is correct in that the custom document can be opened from Messages if it conforms to `public.text`.  The drawback to this solution is that the document is previewed as raw text, which might not be the desired result.

Documents conforming to `public.data` can be opened from the Messages app without being previewed as raw text by creating a Quick Look Preview Extension.  There isn't much documentation about how to build a Quick Look Preview Extension, but it's pretty straightforward:

1. In Xcode, choose, `File` > `New` > `Target`.
2. Choose **Quick Look Preview Extension**, give your extension a name, and click **Finish**.
3. In the `info.plist` for the newly created extension, add a new item under `NSExtension` > `NSExtensionAttributes` > `QLSupportedContentTypes`, and set the value for this item to your app's custom document type.  For example:

   ```
   ...
   <key>NSExtension</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
       <dict>
           <key>QLSupportedContentTypes</key>
           <array>
               <string>com.company.abc.wd</string>
           </array>
           <key>QLSupportsSearchableItems</key>
           <true/>
       </dict>
       <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
       <string>MainInterface</string>
       <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
       <string>com.apple.quicklook.preview</string>
   </dict>
   ...
   ```
4. Use `MainInterface.storyboard` and `PreviewViewController` to define the layout of your custom Quick Look preview.  More specifically, read data from the URL provided in the `preparePreviewOfFile` function and populate the ViewController accordingly.  A brief example (in Swift 4):

   ```
   func preparePreviewOfFile(at url: URL, completionHandler handler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
       do {
           let documentData = try Data(contentsOf: url)

           // Populate the ViewController with a preview of the document.

           handler(nil)
       } catch let error {
           handler(error)
       }
   }
   ```

Some pitfalls I ran into when creating my extension:

- The exported UTI identifier had to be all lower case.  When some of the characters were upper case, the Quick Look preview was never shown, even though I used the same capitalization in my Quick Look Preview Extension.
- Quick Look Preview Extensions are not allowed to link against dynamic libraries.  If a dynamic library is linked, the Quick Look preview will not load.
- The Quick Look ViewController is not allowed to have any buttons.  If it contains a button, the Quick Look preview will not load.

Additional resources:

- [Building Great Document-based Apps in iOS 11 (WWDC 2017 Video)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/229/?time=3102)
- [Quick Look Previews from the Ground Up (WWDC 2018 Video)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/237/?time=1544)
- [QuickLook Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook)

Comment: In iOS 14.7 I found that I could open my custom file format from the Files app but tapping one of those files in Messages did nothing.  By adding a dirt simple Quick Look for my file type I was able to see that when tapping my file in Messages.  From that preview I made I could then send-to my app as desired.  In the Files app it seemed to have its own quick-look that just didn't work from Messages (until I made my own).

Comment: Can't for the life of me make this work. I am following your steps but nothing is happening. I am creating the new build target but I don't understand how to get it  to build? For the moment I am just creating it, editing its info.plist, and then building and running my normal app target. Not sure how the 2 should communicate? My files work perfectly in Mail/Files/Airdrop.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this post while searching for a similar solution. I was able to email custom files from my app and open it in email or use it with AirDrop. If I sent it via iMessage it even showed up with my custom icon, but when I tapped it in iMessage nothing happened.

Be aware that you need something like the following in your plist file (from [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application))

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.plain-text</string>
        <string>public.text</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
    <string>Molecules Structure File</string>
    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.sunsetlakesoftware.molecules.pdb</string>
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <string>pdb</string>
        <key>public.mime-type</key>
        <string>chemical/x-pdb</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

NOTE: I had something very similar for my app BUT in the UTTypeConformsTo I only had public.data since my files are zipped data files.

I found that by adding public.text as a second item in the array it would be actionable in iMessage.  On a further note, if I added public.plain-text as a third item my file ended up with a Pages icon instead of my icon (so I removed it)

I hope this helps someone. It's taken me hours to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I haven't been able to make this solution work.  My device is running iOS 11.  This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/39709981 suggests that something changed with iOS 10.  Is your App still opening iMessage attachments OK with iOS 11?

Answer (score 1):

The value in your Info.plist for the `LSItemContentTypes` key should equal what is declared by your Meeting object.

Presumably your Meeting object adheres to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. Make sure the value you return (from the delegate method `activityViewController:dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType:`) matches the value you have declared as readable in your `Info.plist`.