# How do iOS apps directly launch on tapping a document in Files or Messages instead of just with Open In?

Tags: ios, swiftui, info.plist

My SwiftUI scene-based app has `.onOpenURL()` implemented and I can successfully open my custom file type that is "shared" with it. But, since I'm the only app for my custom file I want my app to just launch on tapping the file. This is not a "document-based app"

If you have a .xlsx or even generic .csv document in Files and the Excel app installed, tapping the document switches directly to the full Excel app, without Files showing a blank placeholder then needing to press the share button.

Here is my relevant info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>My App Document</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.myappname.tc-document</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

and custom Exported UTI:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>My App Document (tc)</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.myappname.tc-document</string>
            <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>tc</string>
                    <string>TC</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

So far I have tried adding to the CFBundleDocumentTypes:

```
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
```

But this didn't seem to change anything, and then I got a

> The application supports opening files, but doesn't declare whether it supports opening them in place. You can add an LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace entry or an UISupportsDocumentBrowser entry to your Info.plist to declare support.

warning from the compiler.

Also interesting is I can use Open-In from a mail attachment, but if I send my file as an iMessage I can't even launch Open-In and thus can't do anything with it from Messages.

Comment: have you tried to add an `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` entry, as suggested by compiler? `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`: "A Boolean value indicating whether the app may open the original document from a file provider, rather than a copy of the document."

Comment: @Scriptable thank you, turns out before I was adding the LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace key to the CFBundleDocumentTypes but it's supposed to just go in the main info.plist dict. So now I can tap in Files and launch my app, but now my code can't determine if it should call `.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement all of the features on iOS:

1. There is no need for the `CFBundleTypeRole` key, it seems to be [for Mac apps](http://cocoadev.github.io/CFBundleTypeRole/).
2. Add the `<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key> <true/>` key to the main dict in info.plist, which will make files you tap open directly in the app as well as regular Open-In.
3. To add the support for opening documents in place, implement a subclass of `UIDocument`. At the minimum, add the `init(url: URL)` and `override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?)`.
   The UIDocument will handle whether the url is security scoped or not, so no need to call `.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` yourself. The UIDocument will also handle asynchronously waiting for an iCloud Drive file to download.
4. In the `.onOpenURL { url in }` or elsewhere call your `UIDocumentSubclass(url: url).open(completionHandler:)`

Comment: Is UIDocument needed? Using configuration question shows + standalone key LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace set true,  app opens instantly from doc on iCloud. Calls SceneDelegate method. However. I need to do `if let url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {  defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() } ... }` before accessing  url.  My Problem is I can't get export type w/UTTypeConformsTo  set to `public.data` to do *anything* when tapped in Messages ,if app no running, but UTTypeConforms to public.json works, but shows text in viewer, THEN I can launch app w/doc from share sheet.

Comment: E.g. for doc that doesn't conform to a public.text derivative, I can't get the app to launch from Messages... only launches if I tap file in iCloud iDrive folder. Whereas if the type is exported conforming to a text document type, I *can* get app to launch from attachment in Messages, but FIRST Messages shows me viewer with my doc contents (when I tap attachment), and it's only the VIEWER that  shows a share icon, of which tapping launches a share sheet, on which I can tap my app's AppIcon and then it will opens my app w/ URL of document. Too many steps and too convoluted. Is there a fix?

Comment: @clearlight I can confirm on latest iOS 16.6, and if I iMessage a Google Sheet .gsheet file, tapping on it does not work. I’m speculating this may be a BlastDoor limitation. Text based documents sort of work maybe because the Viewer is an iMessage app.

Comment: So it seems like its not actually possible to open non text/media files directly by tapping on an attachment on a Messages conversation? I guess its safer, but it really sucks regarding user experience.

Comment: @Hamster I found this answer that may be helpful for the Public.data type to at least match the functionality of the iMessage preview-then-share-button UI https://stackoverflow.com/a/51699268/5818848.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response @JosephDvorak. Regrettably I tried that answer and couldn't get it to work. I think a recent iOS version may have removed this feature.